# Is it possible to "return a return statement"?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to return a return statement in C++ or to do something with similar functionality?

This would be handy if, for example, there are several functions in the code which take a pointer as an input and each of them checks if the pointer is a nullptr or not. If it is a nullptr the function should stop whatever it is doing and return `0`, or whatever is appropriate for its type.

Let `inputPtr` be an `int*` given to a function which returns an `int`. Instead of writing things like

```
    ...
    if(inputPtr == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    }
    ...
```

every time, it would be cool to just have

```
    ...
    checkNull(inputPtr);
    ...
```

or something similar.
In this example it's not too bad of course, but imagine a more elaborate testing function.

Conceptually, this seems to be quite weird. But usually there is a way to prevent repetition.

Comment: How about #define ?

Comment: If the pointer should never be null, throw an exception from  checkNull

Comment: The closest thing to that would be to throw an exception. Technically a macro can do it but it's not recommended.

Comment: Just do ```return checkNull(inputPtr);```

Comment: Or you do it like the experts and just call `std::terminate()`.

Comment: @AidanWelch nope, that won't do.

Comment: @Timo that depends on the contract.

Comment: @AidanWelch How would the OP be able to do that multiple times?

Comment: @SergeyA yeah there was a little bit of sarcasm in my comment.

Comment: Doing the `if` check is more explicit and makes it clear what you're doing.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think I misinterpreted the question, I guess was the point writing ```return func();``` would take too long?

Comment: @AidanWelch The op wants to do ``stuff; if(pointer == nullptr) return somevalue; more_stuff; if(another_pointer == nullptr) return somevalue; even_more_stuff;`  You can't do that with `return checkNull(inputPtr);` as you'll always exit the function at that point.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, I see.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting comments up to now.
Note that the `nullptr` should be understood just as an example at that point. The thing gets more ugly if I want to do more lengthy checks, e.g. if I want to check certain properties of a bunch of numbers in a vector or something similar.
Seems like macros are the only way out (or just copy the code)...

Comment: What you're asking isn't a bad question, but the way it's presented is confusing. You may want to try to come up with a better title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible, and hiding control flow might be considered a bad idea in any event.  If you have to write the checking function, it is simple enough to make that return a Boolean then:

```
if(checkNull(inputPtr)) return 0 ;
```

Comment: Very simple and, importantly, scalable solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is one the very few things which can only be solved with macro in C++.

That is, you really can't stand extra `if` in the code **and** you have a wide contract, which allows for `nullptr`s to be given as arguments.

I personally would not use macro and would just use clear `if` statements.

Comment: It can also be solved with exceptions, but I guess those are a bit of a taboo in C++, eh?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel It is not clear what OP's contract is. If contract is wide, than exception is not really a solution. Also, exception would require the same construct with `if` block. Exceptions are certainly not a taboo, they just are misused occasionally, and people sometimes are getting wary about them.

Comment: The `if` could be hidden within the function that throws, which means the caller doesn't need to do the check again, just call `throw_if_pointer_is_null()` or whatever. The plus side is you don't have to use macros. The downside is you have to use exceptions. Depending on the rest of the code, it might end up as a "pick your poison" situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three options basically:

1. Macros
2. Exceptions
3. [`gsl::not_null`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)

here you have good post about it. https://www.bfilipek.com/2017/10/notnull.html
(of course it is not perfect solution but it may save you some time:))

Comment: A deeper explanation of these would make this answer better.